# React native: Native module cannot be null

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

When I build my project in iOS I get the following errors in that specific order:

```
No component found for view with name "RCTRawText"

No component found for view with name "RCTText"

Unhandled JS Exception: Requiring module "Linking", which threw an exception: Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.

ExceptionsManager.js:73 Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in NavigationContainer (at index.js:13)
    in Provider (at index.js:12)
    in ReactHome (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:113)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
    in RCTView (at View.js:113)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
```

I found that this post could help but the errors persist.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you solve it? like?

Answer (score 2):

Adding RCTText in ios/Podfile file solved this error for me:

```
target 'YourProject' do

  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/', subspecs: [

    ...,

    'RCTText'
  ]

  ...
end
```

This error is probably with react-native versions older than 0.60.0, bacause in later versions it is automatically added when you upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import Linking module from react-native in your NavigationContainer

Comment: Hello Anis! Thanks for your answer. When I try to import Linking module I found that there isn't any .xcodeproj file, only Linking.js. By the other hand RTCLinkingIOS is imported on my Podfile. Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you do to resolve. Please check this thread https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2208